# .avi movie in latex using multimedia package

Tags: multimedia

I am trying to display a movie (avi format) using the multimedia package which I came to know of from Beamer's documentation.

I am using this in the preable:

```
\usepackage{multimedia}
```

I am using this for one of my frames:

```
\begin{frame}{First Frame}
You can see the video below:
\movie[width=3cm,height=2cm,poster]{}{myvideo.avi}
\end{frame}
```

But no video is seen in the PDF. I am working on writelatex.com.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Rohit.

Comment: Is the video file accessible? According to Beamer documentation, it should typically be in the same directory as the PDF file. Also, have you tried different PDF viewers? Another matter: you might want to change `width` and `height` to match the aspect ratio of your video unless it is 3:2.

Comment: No the video resolution is not 3:2. I'll try the exact resolution and see. Thanks anyway :)